# Looking for a string within a list of strings and creating a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and trying to solve the performance issue here.
I have 2 data frames

Dataframe 1

```
col1        col2
holiday     party
party       party
bagel       snack
fruit       snack
```

Data Frame 2:

```
col1                            col2
bagel wednesday                 snack               
coffee for party                snack
holiday party                   party
```

Data Frame 1 has 2 columns. I need to lookup DataFrame1.col1, in DataFrame2.col1 and create a new column in DataFrame2.col2 with DataFrame1.col2 value
Currently, I am achieving this using a loop and it is taking a very long time. I am looking for an efficient way to do this. Also, if I get multiple matches I should always go with the first match found from DataFrame1. For example, "coffee for party" has 2 matches from DF1, snack and party, in which case "snack" should be picked from DF1.col2.

Thanks
RL

Comment: Here are the dataframes:df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
                   'col2': ['weekday','weekday','weekday','weekday','weekday','weekend','weekend',]})    
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['leaving Friday', 'sight seeing Saturday Tuesday', 'break day', 'Monday is working'],
                   'col2': ['weekday','weekend','','weekday']})

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to loop over the days of the week (but not all the rows of df2 (well, df.col.str.contains will do the inner loop for you in an optimized manner)).

```
for item in df1.col2.unique():
    for idx, row in df1[df1.col2==item].iterrows():
        df2.loc[df2.col1.str.contains(row.col1), 'col3'] = item
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It works well but I did not mention one other thing. I have taken a different example this time. The words in col 1 can occur in any order in df2.col1 string.contains does not work for this:                                       
              Dataframe 1

    col1   col2
    ice cream   snack
    cold drink  beverage


Data Frame 2:

    col1                   col2
    ice and cream            snack
    cold drink                           beverage
    break day  
    ice cream                    snack

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Update the original question with an example.

Comment: I changed the example now. Can you please take a look and tell me how to proceed?